# Python's Flask Registration Post method 404 error

Tags: python, flask, post

Hello everybody I am new to Flask and I am writing this program and the registration functionality is not working and the error message is really not helping me much so here is the code, error and html view so, anything will be really helpful. python code:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")

    else:
        # check for username
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("Must provide valid username")

        #  check for valid password
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("Must provide valid password")

        # check password matches
        elif not request.form.get("password") == request.form.get("password_confirmation"):
            return apology("Password doesn't match")

        hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
        new_user = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)", username = request.form.get("username"), hash = hash)

        if not new_user:
            return apology("Username take")

        session["user_id"] = new_user

        flash("Welcome!")

        return redirect("/")
```

Html form:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            <input name="password_confrimation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% enblock %}
```

the logs and message:

```
[2020-07-13T18:19:20.336Z]  "GET /templates/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
[2020-07-13T18:19:21.732Z]  "GET /templates/register.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
[2020-07-13T18:19:32.272Z]  "POST /register" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
[2020-07-13T18:19:32.273Z]  "POST /register" Error (404): "Not found"
```

NOTE: the database is already connected with the db file.

Comment: Small change, but could maybe work. Have your tried `@app.route("/register/", methods=["GET", "POST"])` instead of `@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])` (backslash behind register.)

Comment: just tried it, didnt work and got the same logs as before @tjallo

Comment: In the browser this error appears: ```HTTP ERROR 405``` which is weird because a 405 is a method not allowed error and I am explicitly defining the methods.

Comment: I would recommend you to go with url_for. Might be there is some difficulty in finding the /register.     <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="post">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOU are misspilling password_confirmation in your input name
your code:-

```
<input name="password_confrimation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
```

What it should be:-

```
<input name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
```

Comment: I saw it after taking a break, dumb mistake I needed a break. Thanks